# Hover over a lightning : datatable column cell

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning : datatable which has a field called name, Now I plan to have an
initial width for this column which will truncate the value, The issue is I want to make it like if I hover over the text in the cell name it will show the full value.

This is easy if I use table since I can apply a `onmouseover` on the selected row which will show a title of some sort

This is the JSON for name column

```
            "label": "First Name",
            "fieldName": "First_Name__c",
            "initialWidth" : 120,
            "type": "text",
```

after reading some documentations in regards to datatable, there is `typeAttributes : "url"` that has a tooltip, but it's only for URL's

any idea or answer will do, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by using custom data types but the amount of effort required may not be worth it, since they are going to be defined as an inner component you can also use `onmouseover` global events or component event like you described.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation)

[Custom data type example](https://github.com/atskimura/lightning-datatable-custom-datatype-example/tree/master/force-app/main/default)